# How to have only one brush show on page load when using multiple charts in dc.js/d3.js

Tags: d3.js, brush, dc.js, crossfilter

I've created a page using dc.js/d3.js with multiple bar charts and a row chart, and when I hover over them and interact, the brush functionality works as expected in all charts.

I'm trying to get just one of the charts to have the brush and a range appear on page load, but when I try this using .filter on one chart, the other charts become disabled. I have also experimented with .extent.

Image of the two version of the charts:

http://neil-s.com/unison/images/Brush3.png

I have looked at some related posts on SO, but they aren't quite what I need. The main crossfilter page has an example, but since the code is so different, I want to see if I can retain what I have, otherwise I'll use the crossfilter page code.

**Updated:**
Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jth32/22/

And here is a small sample of the bar chart code:

```
    // Bar Chart 3-------------------------------
    psalBarChart
        .width(300).height(150)         
        .dimension(psalDim) 
        .group(psalGroup) 
        .x(d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([25, 40]))      
        .xAxisLabel("Salinity")
        .centerBar(true);

    // Bar Chart 4 -----------------------------------      
    depthBarChart
        .width(300).height(150)         
        .dimension(depthDim) 
        .group(depthGroup) 
        .x(d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 2050]))                         
        .xAxisLabel("Depth")
        .centerBar(true)
        //.filter([0,1000]) // Creates Brush, but disables other charts
```

Thanks

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me.

Comment: The jsfiddle has been updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jth32/22/
I've commented out line 358 in the javascript, which is what causes the other charts to become disabled. Thanks Lars.

Comment: It still seems to be unable to load crossfilter here...

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'm using CDN links for all of the external resources, so I wonder why they're blocked there. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Your original example (with line 358 uncommented) works fine for me. I see the filter on the Depth chart and am able to filter on the other charts if I want. I'm in Chrome - what browser are you seeing the problem in?

Comment: I was having a problem with Firefox and Chrome in my dev testing environment, but now I'm seeing that the fiddle is working correctly. 
The fiddle isn't loading an external json file like my dev version, so that might be the difference. I'll have to do some more experimenting. 
Thanks for catching that Ethan.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it had to do with the version of dc.js that I was using. The latest version on github (v2.0) is what I had, but the CDN link I used in jsfiddle used version 1.6.0, and that works fine as Ethan mentioned. Once I switched to 1.6.0 in my dev environment, that fixed my issue.

I posted a message to the dc-js google user group, and I'll add another message here if this is indeed a bug in dc.js v2.0.